# Assign loaded class to variable within current scope

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup some classes to work with, but I'm not really sure how to accomplish to following.

Let's say I have a class "foo" that I'm working in, and I want to use functions from another class called "loader". The purpose of this loader class is to load various other classes that I can then use within the "foo" class.

Example:

```
class foo {
    function foo() {
        $this->load->model();
    }
}
```

For this to work I would first initiate the class "load":

```
class foo {
    function foo() {
        $this->load = new loader;
        $this->load->model('some_model');
    }
}
```

Now I can use the functions from within the loader class. The next thing I want is for the loaded model to be accessible from within the class foo. Example:

```
class foo {
    function foo() {
        $this->load = new loader;
        $this->load->model('some_model');
        $this->some_model->function_from_this_model();
    }
}
```

And this is where I get lost, because I'm not sure how to stay within the scope of the "foo" class. At any given time I'd like to be able to use `$this->load->model('some_model')` to load a new model, that becomes accessible through `$this->some_model`. Or `$this->load->something_else('some_name')` which becomes available through `$this->some_name`.

Here's a loader class example:

```
class loader {
    function model($model_name) {
        require('models/'.$model_name.'.php');
        $model = new $model_name;
        // and what to do now, to get it back to the $this var from class foo?
    }
}
```

But all of this happens only within the scope of the loader class.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**Edit**:
I know I can assign it directly to a variable, like `$this->model_name` = `$this->load->model('model_name')`, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to be able to use this "load" subclass to be able to work within the scope of the class "foo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Singleton, which will allow you to initialize your class objects from another class.

Example:

```
// Loader will access class singleton and set object
class loader {
    function model($model_name, $class) {
        require('models/'.$model_name.'.php');
        $class::init()->$model_name = new $model_name;
    }
}

// see new singleton methods
class foo {

    private static $instance
    public static function init(){
        if(is_null(self::$instance)){
            $class = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $class;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    function foo() {
        $this->load = new loader;
        $this->some_model = $this->load->model('some_model', __CLASS__);
        $this->some_model->function_from_this_model();
    }
}

// init class like this
foo::init()->foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok after your edit here's the method I would suggest
Change your classes, as per below:

Your loader needs to [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) the model you have initiated:

```
class loader {
    function static load_model($model_name, $object) {
        require('models/'.$model_name.'.php');
        $class = new $model_name;
        $object->$model_name = $class;
        return $object;
    }
}
```

And now you can use:

```
class foo {

    public function foo($model)
    {
       return loader::load_model($model, $this);
    }
}

$class = new foo();
$class->foo('some_model');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that from a composition standpoint you would be better of attaching your loader class to the foo class via a method.  So rather than having to have includes within each class to make other classes available, you would just attach the loader/model etc to the class. So something like this:

```
class foo {
    protected $loader = NULL;
    protected $model = NULL;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function attach_loader(loader $loader) {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function load_model(model $model) {
        $this->model = $this->loader->load($model);
    }
}
```

This allow you the ability to attach any loader (or descendant of loader that supports a load() method to the class and utilize it to load any model (or descendent) into your class. The class itself doesn't need to know where these class files are located, just that they items it is operating on have to be of a certain type.